# How can i check is my program crash?

Tags: c#, winforms, connection

I'm making an OPC client on winforms, client that connecting with server and reading data from it with OPC protocol. So, I successfull connecting to server, but when my program crashing or I'm closing it manually from task manager, connection with server is still exist (and that's not good).

Can I somehow check my program for correct ending ? And if my program ends incorrect then disconnect from server.

I tried to use `myProcess.HasExited`, but it's not working.

Comment: Hi Ramon, please read this and edit your question accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Since you've suggested a `Process` component to this question, I assume you are launching an EXE and asking how to monitor it.  Why do that?  Why is the EXE _itself_ not responsible for gracefully closing the connection when something goes wrong?  It's highly unlikely you would be able to handle that from a distance...

Comment: I actually don't know. I thought so too

Answer (score -1):

I can only guess you can use Socket for server connection. If so, then this is a good practice to close it once you've done with server call. You need to call sequence of `Shutdown()`, `Close()`, `Dispose()`.

See this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using someone's homemade library for OPC, and there already had Disconnect methods. But i just dont know how to disconnect if program crash.

Comment: You need to subscribe to "catch all unhandled exception" events. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32396235/1786034