# c# UnhandeledExceptionEventHandler not working with throw new Exception

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled-exception

So I have this Exception handler built into my application and when I'm using:

```
throw new Exception("Message here");
```

Nothing is happening, it's not then running my Handler function for some reason, does anyone know why this might be occuring and if so, what I can do to correct this? Ideally, I'd like to route all exceptions to this function.

```
static class Program
{
    private static void ExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ExceptionObject != null)
        {
            LoggerUtility.SendErrorEmail("[ERROR] - " + e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Program.ExceptionHandler);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because WinForms catches it in it's event loop.

Comment: CodeInChaos, I noticed the same thing as well, is there a way around that to globally catch / redirect all exceptions to a particular function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014562/whats-the-difference-between-application-threadexception-and-appdomain-currentd)