# Can't see exception on client pc

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

When there is an exception on my c# app an exception windows is shown on my pc like above. But When exception occured on my friends pc nothing shown to the user only the error message "Application stop working". Why It is different my pc and my friend pc.

[image: On my PC Exception is shown]

[image: on my friend PC]

Not:Exceptions that you see in pict are different, on my pc application is working well , to show exception i do it manually

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges, a CLR20r3 error is a whole different beast than a .Net Exception.

Comment: The "full" error might be logged to the Windows Application log.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014562/whats-the-difference-between-application-threadexception-and-appdomain-currentd)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes more information about exception and stacktrace is in event viewer. But the real question that i want to ask is why is the dialogs are different, but i found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unhandled exception dialog is only shown for exceptions occurred on UI thread. If the exception on remote machine occurred on a different thread that might be the cause.

It could also be related to Windows Error Reporting settings under Control Panel\System and Security\Action Center\Problem Reporting Settings

Comment: Thanks, I found that with help of your answer, UI Thread exceptions are handled by default, first picture is ThreadExceptionDialog which is shown by the exception handler. Second one is for all the exceptions that is not catched.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a lot more information needed to try to diagnose this. This ones I would start with are: What are the environments of you and your friend's set ups, i.e.

- Versions of Windows
- Installation of service packs
- versions of .NET
- version of SQL Server etc.