# Event handler when Application bugs

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, event-handling

What event can handle when application shuts down due to a bug ? 
 thanks

Update : 
My point is that I want to excute some code in case of any bug due to unhandled exception in the whole application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014562/whats-the-difference-between-application-threadexception-and-appdomain-currentd)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can even put an exception handler around `Application.Run`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
  static class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      try
      {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(
          exception.Message +
          exception.StackTrace,
          "Error",
          MessageBoxButtons.OK,
          MessageBoxIcon.Error
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I wouldn't leave this in a production app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.ThreadException` event. But like others suggested, try to catch your exceptions in place and provide a meaningful logic for those circumstances.