# How do I disable error dialog box in VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exception

If an app creates an exception, Windows pauses and displays an error dialog box. The user can decide to close the app.

How do I disable this box? (Yes I know about Try, Catch, Finally but I want to disable it globally for the application.) I want to display MyErrorForm.vb instead of the standard error box, or disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! Put in Program.cs (Main file) this code:

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

(Put it before `Application.Run`) and ad error handling:

```
private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
     //TODO: Handle error...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook:

- [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Application.ThreadException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

See [What's the difference between Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014562/whats-the-difference-between-application-threadexception-and-appdomain-currentd) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Add code module file to your project, name it UnhandledExceptions.vb followed by adding the following code that replaces the default content.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices
Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Indicates if we are running under the IDE or not
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <value></value>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        Public ReadOnly Property RunningUnderDebugger() As Boolean
            Get
                Return System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
            End Get
        End Property
        Private mUnhandledExceptionsFileName As String
        Public Property UnhandledExceptionsFileName() As String
            Get
                Return mUnhandledExceptionsFileName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                mUnhandledExceptionsFileName = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private mExceptionDialogIcon As Icon
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Specifically used to set the exception dialog's icon
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <value></value>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        Public Property ExceptionDialogIcon() As Icon
            Get
                Return mExceptionDialogIcon
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Icon)
                mExceptionDialogIcon = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private mContinueAfterException As Boolean
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Determine if this app can stay open after an unhandled
        ''' exception has been thrown.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <value></value>
        ''' <returns></returns>
        ''' <remarks>
        ''' Not practical in most circumstances as we usually
        ''' do not know how to hangle unhandled exceptions and
        ''' leaving an app open will not be wise.
        ''' </remarks>
        Public Property ContinueAfterException() As Boolean
            Get
                Return Not mContinueAfterException
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                mContinueAfterException = value
            End Set
        End Property
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Displays a user friendly message in regards to the 
        ''' unhandled exception.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="sender"></param>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        ''' <remarks>
        ''' It would be wise to also write to a log file etc.
        ''' 
        ''' WARNING 
        ''' If you use code prone to errors in here then you will not 
        ''' be very happy so test test test before implementing.
        ''' </remarks>
        Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(mUnhandledExceptionsFileName) Then
                mUnhandledExceptionsFileName = "unHandledExceptions.xml"
            End If

            Dim Doc As New XDocument

            If IO.File.Exists(My.Application.UnhandledExceptionsFileName) Then
                Doc = XDocument.Load(My.Application.UnhandledExceptionsFileName)
            Else
                Doc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Exceptions></Exceptions>")
            End If

            Dim Content = Doc.<Exceptions>(0)
            Dim StackTraceText As String = e.Exception.StackTrace.ToString

            Content.Add(
            <Exception>
                <Date_Time><%= Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") %></Date_Time>
                <Message><%= e.Exception.Message %></Message>
                <StackTrace><%= Environment.NewLine %>
                    <%= StackTraceText %><%= Environment.NewLine %>
                </StackTrace>
            </Exception>)

            Content.Save(My.Application.UnhandledExceptionsFileName)

            ' here I am using a form setup specifically to show exceptions
            'Dim f As New frmExceptionDialog
            'f.InBoundException = e.Exception
            'f.Message = String.Format("Exception has been recorded to [{0}]", My.Application.UnhandledExceptionsFileName)
            'f.Header = "Unhandled exception"


            'Try
            '    f.ShowDialog()
            'Finally
            '    f.Dispose()
            'End Try

            MessageBox.Show("Encountered an exception" & Environment.NewLine & e.Exception.Message)


            e.ExitApplication = Me.ContinueAfterException

            If Me.ContinueAfterException Then
                Me.ContinueAfterException = False
            End If

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Example usage in your startup form

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ExceptionLogFile As String = ""
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        My.Application.UnhandledExceptionsFileName = "unHandledExceptions.xml"
        ExceptionLogFile = My.Application.UnhandledExceptionsFileName
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        If My.Application.RunningUnderDebugger Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please execute from Window's Explorer")
            Application.ExitThread()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Throw New Exception("Hey")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Output generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Exceptions>
  <Exception>
    <Date_Time>02/10/2016 15:45</Date_Time>
    <Message>Hey</Message>
    <StackTrace>
   at WindowsApplication3.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Dotnet_Development\Projects_Non_Business\WindowsApplication3\Form1.vb:line 16
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
</StackTrace>
  </Exception>
</Exceptions>
```

I used xml but you could easily use a text file or other type of file. When I was doing this type of working with exceptions the code would also send me an email message.

See also which has the custom form to display messages rather than a MessageBox.
[Dealing with unhandled exceptions in Window's form solutions](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Dealing-with-unhandled-9b933818)

IMPORTANT: In the first file there is a property, ContinueAfterException, this under 99 percent of the time be set to false as setting it to true will allow (if possible) the app to stay active but more likely than not unstable.