# Schoolboy issue with exceptions in VB winforms - Can't find exception types?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, exception

I've got a problem with finding exceptions that I can't seem to get any help via google for. Unsurprising as Visual Studio can't seem to decide whether it can find these types or not.

This is a Winforms app that I'm trying to add a reasonable (temporary!) top level try-catch to. However, despite not needing to import any namespaces AND VS being indecisive, it will not compile with these exceptions in place. If you see the first image, it's decided they don't exist.
[image: Now it's fine - it's lying]
[image: Now it's not happy]

```
Public Sub MainTry(action As Action)
    Dim subname = If(NameOf(action) IsNot Nothing, NameOf(action), "anonymous")
    Try
        action()
    Catch ex As Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException 'Also tried    Catch ex As Application.ThreadException
        ErrorHelper.Log(ex, "ThreadException", subname)
    Catch ex As System.AppDomain.UnhandledException
        ErrorHelper.Log(ex, "", subname)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorHelper.Log(ex, "General Exception", subname)
    Finally
        If MsgBox("Do you wish to restart TMS?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, app_name) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Application.Restart()
        Else
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

If anyone can explain why VS 2015 is being such a pain about these exception types I'd be grateful.

The project does use Office Interop and Devexpress winforms - the tooltip help does pop up with alternatives from these libraries, I've tried being explicit with naming and so on, this hasn't helped!

Comment: Looks like you have to create a handler for these types of exceptions. Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not exceptions. If you look at your picture it says:

> **Event** Application.ThreadException As ThreadExceptionEventHandler

[**`AppDomain.UnhandledException`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`Application.ThreadException`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx) are [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx) that are raised when an exception occurs that *is not* caught by a `Try/Catch` statement (this is also the reason why they are events).

If you want to handle them you can subscribe to the events in the form's `Load` event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf AppDomain_UnhandledException
    AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf Application_ThreadException
End Sub

Private Sub AppDomain_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    ErrorHelper.Log(DirectCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception), "UnhandledException", "")
End Sub

Private Sub Application_ThreadException(sender As Object, e As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
    ErrorHelper.Log(e.Exception, "ThreadException", "")
End Sub
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2014684/3740093) and the documentation the difference between the two events is that `Application.ThreadException` is fired when an exception is unhandled in a WinForms owned thread (those exceptions you can choose to ignore and execution will continue), whereas the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event is raised once an exception is unhandled in a non-WinForms thread or when the `ThreadException` is disabled.

Apart from `Application.ThreadException`, when an unhandled exception occurs that causes the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event to be raised, the program execution cannot continue.

Comment: Hi Vincent, thank you! When I found the exceptions elsewhere online this difference wasn't clear to me. I knew it would be something fundamental. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths : No problem. The actual difference is that the actual exceptions are classes, while these two are events _indicating_ that an exception has been thrown. -- You can check the object type that IntelliSense shows you. If the `***Exception` is a class, then you'll most likely be able to use it in a `Catch`-statement.